# How to write "von" as part of family names, especially at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: prefix

How do you write "von" properly? Do you write it with  capitalised v if you write von in the beginning of sentence? Which one is correct, "von Brun" or "Von Brun" if you want to write it as name lets say on a note or a memo?

Answer (score 10):

1. The first letter of any sentence is capitalised.
2. > Alle zu einem mehrteiligen Namen gehörenden Adjektive, Partizipien, Pronomen und Zahlwörter schreibt man groß <§ 60>.

   prepositions and articles are written as you usually write them: Johann Wolfgang von Goethe, der Schiefe Turm von Pisa, Lutz van der Horst

Comment: Not allways: [Alexander **V**an der Bellen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Van_der_Bellen)

Answer (score 3):

*Von* is written *von* everywhere except where a capital letter is required by the normal capitalization rules, for example at the beginning of this sentence

Answer (score 1):

According to Duden, the Adelsprädikat, if spelt out, is written as “Von” at the beginning of a sentence, but if it is abbreviated then it is always “v.” even at the beginning of a sentence.

See this: https://gfds.de/kleinschreibung-am-satzanfang/